# How to change grid item's height (load more button) without breaking css grid layout

Tags: css, css-grid

i have a load more button in the **bio section** which reveals some info
but there is a ***white space*** that appears between courses and articles
as the height of my bio section increases which ends up breaking my layout
as i want to display articles below the courses directly

how can i fix it?

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(".extra").classList.toggle("toggle");
})
```

```css
#grid{
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: masonry;
}


#bio{
    grid-column: 1/2;
    border: 3px solid green;
}
#courses{
    grid-column: 2/4;
    grid-row: 1/3;
}
#badges{
        grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 2/4;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    
}
#articles{
        grid-column: 2/4;
    grid-row: 3/5;

}
#likes{
    grid-column: 1/2;
        border: 3px solid red;

}

/*for the ui*/
.articles{
    display: flex;
}

.article{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 5px;
}
.extra{
    display: none;
}
.toggle{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div id="bio">
        <p>Bio</p>
        <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

icon
Egypt

icon
5 march, 2022

icon
ahmed@ahmedmostafa.com

icon
www.ahmedmostafa.com</div>
        <div class="extra">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
            of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
        </div>
        <button>load more</button>
    </div>
    <div id="courses">
        <p>articles</p>
        <div class="articles">
            <div class="article"></div>
        <div class="article"></div>
        <div class="article"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="badges">
        <p>badges</p>
        <ul>
            <li>first</li>
            <li>secound</li>
            <li>third</li>
            <li>fourth</li>
            <li>first</li>
            <li>secound</li>
            <li>third</li>
            <li>fourth</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div id="articles">
        <p>articles</p>
        <div class="articles">
            <div class="article"></div>
        <div class="article"></div>
        <div class="article"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="likes">
        <p>badges</p>
        <ul>
            <li>first</li>
            <li>secound</li>
            <li>third</li>
            <li>fourth</li>
            <li>first</li>
            <li>secound</li>
            <li>third</li>
            <li>fourth</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

*here's my solution*

Comment: You're aware that masonry grid features are only supported by Firefox at this stage, and only by setting a specific flag? https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_grid-template-rows_masonry

Comment: @BrettDonald hi, i'm not using the grid-template-rows: masonry feature as i know it's a new born feature.
i'm using only cols and rows to achieve the layout is it not possible?

Comment: I only mentioned it because your code includes `#grid {grid-template-rows: masonry;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem arises because the grid rows expand to fit their contents. So if you add more content, the row has to get larger to accommodate.

My solution uses the grid to position the columns, but **not the rows**. Everything is contained within a single grid row.

**Update**

Following the comments received, I have now updated this solution so that on narrow screens, the columns are styled to disappear from the DOM tree (using `display: contents;`) and the grid then contains a single column with multiple rows, and the different sections can be placed in specific rows if desired.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(".extra").classList.toggle("toggle");
})
```

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(0, 2fr); /* https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/ */
  overflow: hidden;
}

#bio {
  border: 3px solid lime;
}

#courses {
  border: 3px solid cyan;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#badges {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

#articles {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#likes {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.articles {
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.article {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.extra {
  display: none;
}

.toggle {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {

  #grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }

  #col1, #col2 {
    display: contents;
  }

  #courses {
    grid-row: 2;
  }

  #articles {
    grid-row: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="col1">
    <div id="bio">
      <p>Bio</p>
      <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

icon
Egypt

icon
5 march, 2022

icon
ahmed@ahmedmostafa.com

icon
www.ahmedmostafa.com
      </div>
      <div class="extra">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
            of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
      </div>
      <button>load more</button>
    </div>
    <div id="badges">
      <p>badges</p>
      <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>secound</li>
        <li>third</li>
        <li>fourth</li>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
        <li>third</li>
        <li>fourth</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="likes">
      <p>likes</p>
      <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>secound</li>
        <li>third</li>
        <li>fourth</li>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
        <li>third</li>
        <li>fourth</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="col2">
    <div id="courses">
      <p>courses</p>
      <div class="articles">
        <div class="article"></div>
        <div class="article"></div>
        <div class="article"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="articles">
      <p>articles</p>
      <div class="articles">
        <div class="article"></div>
        <div class="article"></div>
        <div class="article"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and effort to help me with the issue,
the reason why i didn't think of this solution is because in smaller screens the badge section will be at the very top then the col2 content then the rest of the col1 at the very end
that's why i didn't want to wrap the sections in cols
since i didn't specify that in the question, i'll accept it as the right answer, maybe i can use this and duplicate the html and toggle the duplicated with sm/lg screens

Comment: On narrow screens you can use `#col1, #col2 {display: contents;}` to make these wrappers invisible and then the sections become the elements which are positioned by the grid. They effectively move up a level in the DOM tree. I have updated my solution to include a @media rule for narrow screens, to show that you can sort the sections as you desire.